# Difference between google checkout and google shopping

Tags: google-checkout, google-shopping-api

I have a doubt, before asking here I searched a lot but did not get the correct answer. My doubt is what is the difference between Google checkout and Google shopping.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Shopping[1] is a search engine for products - it lets you search for a product and then compare prices across different retailers etc.

Google Checkout/Wallet[2] is a payment services provider, somewhat like PayPal or Stripe. Most popular use is probably for buying things from the google play store. It's been renamed to Google Wallet[3], and can no longer be used for accepting payments for physical goods.

1: http://www.google.com/shopping

2: http://www.google.com/wallet/

3: https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/3080449

Answer (score 0):

Wallet/Checkout allows a user to do the shopping (login/pay) while the Shopping API is more about managing the shop (see: https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/v1/getting_started).